# Vagrant box for Groovy and Grails Development

Tags: grails, groovy, vagrant

I want to use Vagrant to ensure a consistent development environment for my Groovy and Grails projects. Is there are standard base Vagrant box? Ie that comes with Java, GVM, Groovy and Grails pre-installed?

I’ve taken a look and can find two but I had some issues with both:

1. http://borzacchiello.it/set-up-a-vagrant-machine-for-grails-development/
   “An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try again. Couldn't open vag2demo/vagrant-grails/base”
2. https://github.com/osoco/testbox
   Here localhost:8888 went to a tomcat that should have Jenkins running, instead it was a base tomcat installation.

Does anyone know of any other sources for a Groovy and Grails Vagrant box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into similar problems recently and created my own Vagrant box for Grails development.
https://github.com/janmey/grails-vagrant

It's based on Java7 and the latest Groovy and Grails versions are installed using gvm. It's still work-in-progress, but you should be able to get started with it pretty quickly. The inital "vagrant up" will take a while, but the "Hello World" app should work then.